# MySQL. Ссылочная целостность. Не работает ON DELETE RESTRICT

Tags: mysql, база-данных, innodb

Доброго времени суток. Есть таблицы `departments` и `users`. Записи из таблицы юзеров могут иметь ссылку на записи из `departments`, но не обязательно, в определении столбца стоит, что он может быть `NULL`.

Понадобилось установить на них ссылочную целостность, то есть при удалении записи из `departments`, если кто-то в `users` имеет ссылку на нее, то должна вылетать ошибка. Использую такой запрос для установки внешнего ключа:

```
ALTER TABLE `users`
ADD CONSTRAINT `users_ibfk_2` 
FOREIGN KEY (`department_id`) 
REFERENCES `departments` (`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT;
```

И вся запара в том, что это не работает для столбцов, которые могу быть `NULL`. При удалении записи из `departments`, в таблице `users`, значение столбца `department_id` тупо устанавливается в `NULL`. Если запретить `NULL`, то естественно всё работает и ошибка вылетать будет. Но мне нужно что бы столбец мог быть `NULL`. Подскажите что делать. Движок, если что `InnoDB`, просто читал, что это работает только на нём.

Comment: Можно создать отделение "Нет отделения" =)

Comment: NOT NULL необходим, и это не обсуждается. Следовательно, надо воспользоваться решением, которое предлагает **vp_arth**.

Comment: Вариант с NOT NULL во многом предпочтительнее (не нужно изобретать велосипедов, эффективнее используют индексы, упрощаются запросы...). Однако, если NULL всенепременно должен быть разрешен, следует создать триггер, который при попытке удаления записи будет выполнять необходимые проверки. Хотя это костыль.

Comment: @Aleksei, Ладно, я всё понял, спасибо.